# Telerik RadMenu Item NavigateURL with out postack

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

When I click on any of the items in my Radmenu, it's doing a complete postback.  I tried adding a OnClientItemClicking method, but didn't help.  I kept my radmenu inside a radajaxpanel, but still the same behavior occurs.

Can this be avoided by any chance?

```
function OnClientItemClicking(sender, args) {
      args.set_cancel(true);
}  

<telerik:RadMenu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" Skin="Office2010Silver"
    OnClientItemClicking="OnClientItemClicking" Width="100%" Font-Bold="true">
   <Items>
        <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Main.aspx" Text="Home">
        </telerik:RadMenuItem>
   </Items>
 </telerik:RadMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ( I didn't try it my self but it should work.

```
                    <telerik:RadMenuItem>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <a href="http://www.yahoo.com">yahoo</a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `RadMenuItem` has a property [`PostBack`](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/p_telerik_web_ui_radmenuitem_postback.html) which you can set to false to prevent a postback.